# Xamarin form app net getting start

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Using Visual Studio 2015:-
I am Having issue with visual studio when running xamarin form app, I have attached the screen shot, after close this window this error message is coming.

> System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener' not found.

Please help me guys if have any idea regarding this. 
[image]

Comment: Again i have added new project , its looking for Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener

Answer (score 2):

Try to update  "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" & "Xamarin.Forms" Nuget Packages

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77924/missingmethodexception-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout-adddrawerlistener-not-found). It's probably because of a corrupted Xamarin.Forms template.